# Finding correct service for arcpy.createArcSDEconnectionFile_management in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, python-addin

I'm working on a toolbar for modifying an SDE database in acrmaps. My code works in a file geodatabase so I'm trying to use this function to make it work in an ArcSDE. I've gotten every other variable in this function figured out, but I have no idea how to find the service variable. I did find some commands for that in arcmaps 9.3, but I am using 10.3 and the command console has been removed.

How do I figure out what the ArcSDE service name or TCP port number is? Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the documentation on the function:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-arcsde-connection-file.htm

Comment: Is using direct connect an option, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-database-connection.htm? This is preferred as SDE services (Three Tier connections) are depreciated. If must use a three tier connection your SDE administrator will be able to tell you the service name, 5150 and 5151 are the most common ones I have come across (they correspond to the port number).

Comment: @Dowlers what's the difference? I'm pretty new to this as it is. Do they do the same thing? How would I know if it weren't an option? I'm looking at it now and I don't seen any reason that it wouldn't work.

Comment: "Direct connect" connects directly to the database instance. "Three Tier" or "SDE service" connections connect to an SDE service. The SDE service handles the connection to the database behind the scenes, kind of like a proxy. Try making a new database connection in ArcCatalog under Database connections<add Database Connection . By default it will give you direct connect connection type. See if that works.

Comment: @Dowler I need a solution that works in a script for a toolbar I'm making. Your explanation does make a bit of sense though. Can I use this to connect to a versioned editing session? For some reason I can't open a workspace in a version session. I found a question here that made a script written for a file geodatabase work for an SDE database. I think this is the logic used there.

Comment: 10.3 doesn't have application servers, so the point is moot. If you design your tool to consume a connection file (.sde), you can remove all the wheel reinventing.

Comment: @Vince how does a tool consume a connection file?

Comment: @Steve I'm currently try to figure out what types of connections your SDE accepts. That will determine what type of .sde connection file to use. Vince is right that 10.3 SDE doesn't even provide an sde service to connect to but your SDE could be an older version while your client is 10.3. How do you connect to SDE outside of python, just using ArcMap?

Comment: Make the file path a parameter.  Done.

Comment: @Dowlers just using ArcMap

Comment: @Vince Would this be the file path to the database I'm editing or the version I'm editing?

Comment: How in ArcMap? You need to create a connection file of one type or the other for ArcMap to use. Just use this connection file in you script as Vince says if you don't want to programmatically create one.

Comment: @Dowlers I can't open the workspace when I try to use the version.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking anymore. Have you tried to create a direct connect connection like the arcpy function I linked to in my first comment? If so did it work? If not what was the error?

Comment: @Dowlers This is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\153289\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.3\AssemblyCache\{0BEF4E61-6332-4BCA-A908-959CA3C0B4E7}\leetScripts_addin.py", line 86, in onClick
    edit = arcpy.da.Editor(outName)#outName is workspace
RuntimeError: cannot open workspace

Comment: This is a completely different question that what you posted. I recommend you start a new question, add your source code and the error message.

Comment: @Dowlers add your first comment as an answer so I can give you credit in solving my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using [direct connect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-database-connection.htm) an option? This is preferred as SDE services (Three Tier connections) are depreciated. If must use a three tier connection your SDE administrator will be able to tell you the service name, 5150 and 5151 are the most common ones I have come across (they correspond to the port number).

Comment: How do I make this point to my version?